# Overwrite git branch while keeping history

Tags: git, git-branch, squash

Our team has been developing 2 versions of a project side by side.

The commits in the `master` branch were basically bugfixes to the old code,
while the `v2setup` branch contains a complete rewrite.

Had those bugfixes not occured I could simply squash the new branch back into the master,
but if I'm not mistaking that will only lead to annoying conflicts now.

So how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to merge master into v2Setup...but for the code at the HEAD be what v2Setup is now, is that correct?

If so, this is actually fairly easy to acheive using the merge strategy "ours"

so merge master into v2Setup with

```
git merge -s ours master
```

***Edit***
Ok, so reading the comments, sounds like you want to move ahead on master, but with the v2Setup changes. So from the above command you can now just merge back into master and you will have what you want.

Or a better option would be to use the theirs strategy from master

```
git merge -X theirs v2Setup
```

Comment: After that you'd end up with master where it was, but v2Setup would be the branch with master's history. Therefore after that you'd checkout master and merge v2Setup into it if you want to continue your work on master :) I never understood why is there no "theirs" strategy, is there any good reason for that?

Comment: Not quite. v2setup branched of master a while ago, and I want to "merge squash" it back on to the master. I thought I could delete all the files in `master`, copy the files from `v2setup` and commit as 1 big change, but I don't know how correct and efficient that is.